# How to echo duplicate lines only one time in for loop?

Tags: php

I have coded this :

```
<?php

    $onlinecheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM online  order by id DESC");
   for($j=1; $onlinecheck1 = mysql_fetch_object($onlinecheck); $j++)
{   
$page               = $onlinecheck1->page;




echo $page;
}

?>
```

and my table is like this :

```
1  index.php
2  index.php
3  contact.php
4  gallery.php
```

It will be printed as like this :

```
   index.php
   index.php
   contact.php
   gallery.php
```

But i want to print like this :

```
   index.php
   contact.php
   gallery.php
```

Help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an associative array whose keys are the names you've printed. Before printing a name, check whether it's already in the array.

```
$pages_printed = array();
for($j=1; $onlinecheck1 = mysql_fetch_object($onlinecheck); $j++)
{   
    $page = $onlinecheck1->page;
    if (!isset($pages_printed[$page])) {
        $pages_printed[$page] = true;
        echo $page;
    }
}
//I have added missed > )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $onlinecheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM online  order by id DESC");
    if ($onlinecheck) {
        $used = array();
        for($j=1; $onlinecheck1 = mysql_fetch_object($onlinecheck); $j++) {   
            $page = $onlinecheck1->page;
            if (!isset($used[$page]) || $used[$page] !== true) {
                $used[$page] = true;
                echo $page;
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to check `$used[$page] !== true`? If it's set, that's the only possible value.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts @user3425372